# How to query the data in this case in MYSQL /SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on online shop project. There are two kinds or order, and for each type of order, they have the same status, the table structure is like this

```
order_type_1
==============
id

order_type_2
==============
id

status
=============
id
status_code
order_type1_id (nullable)
order_type2_id (nullable)
create_date
```

1. I design the status table because the two order has the same kind of status_code, but I wonder is it a good structure, should I separate them into two different table?
2. The status code is like that , e.g. 200 ordering 300 shipping 400 complete, are there any way to get all the order that is shipping (300)?. I have thought of using Between , but it is not the case, the WHERE clause is apply to a row, but not the result set.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: 1. I usually add another column name `category_for_order` to differentiate the kinds of order and for future expansion.

Comment: Maintaining `order_type_table` and `status_table`. Adding the `category_for_order` column in your `status_table`

Comment: how about there will be no expansion? That means the company is fix to that two kind of order

Comment: If your not planning expand at least your informations are organize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I suggest using the Status table as reference only. And add an order type reference table also

```
    status
    =============
    id
    status_code

    order_type
    =============
    id
    order_code
    order_desc
```

then have a single order table

```
    order
    =============
    id
    order_type_id
    status_id
```

and for the query

```
    select * from order o join status s on s.id = o.status_id where s.status_code = 300
```

EDIT:
Structure for multiple status for an order:

```
    order
    =============
    id
    order_type_id

    status
    =============
    id
    status_code

    order_status
    ============
    order_id
    status_id

    order_type
    =============
    id
    order_code
    order_desc
```

The idea is to keep status and order_type tables as reference only which means that you will not perform insert operations on these tables.

as for the query, you could use this:

```
 select * from order o join order_status os on os.order_id = o.id  join status s on os.status_id = s.id where s.status_code in (300,200,100)
```

Comment: I wonder will it harm performance if I put all the order in one table? That means, if there is 9000 row of order 1 , and 1000 row order 2, in my backend I just differenate them into two page, so , if I look at order 2 then I still query 10000 record

Comment: If you want to query all order type 2 then you would have to add where cluase, for example: 'select * from order where order_type_id = 2'. this will return only 1000 records.

Comment: Also, for the query, it can have more than one status code for an order, that means, An order may have 200 ordering 300 shipping 400 complete, 3 status record, so I can not simply use where caluse

Comment: in that case you would have to create a join table for order and status tables

Comment: That means, if the order has 300 as well as 400 I will not include it in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If the order can only have one of two types and is only one status, why not just have orderid, ordertype, orderstatus as a table?

To select using your table design, use

```
SELECT * 
FROM status 
WHERE status_code=300;
```

Comment: yes.. I differentiate them because there is more than one status, that means, the admin can check the time of each status change

Comment: Then use a single status order table holding the id and ordertype, then have a status table that consists of an orderid, status and timestamp.